# Plotting a chessboard in R. How to name columns and rows?

Tags: r, function, plot

I wrote the function, that draws chessboards. I want to name each column and row using the letters. But, I don't know how to do this.

My code:

```
chessboard=function(n){
  if(1<=n & n<=26){
    x=c(1:(n+1))
    y=c(1:(n+1))

    plot(x,y,type="n", yaxt='n',xaxt='n', ann=FALSE)
    for (i in (1:n)) {
      if(i%%2==0){
        col=c("#FFFFFF","#000000")
      }
      else{
        col=c("#000000","#FFFFFF")
        }
      rect(i,1:(n+1),i+1,(n+1), col=col, )
    }
  } 
  else{
    print("wrong!")
  }
  }
```

Now I have :

[image]

But, I want to have:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of what the labels should look like? I thought chess diagrams generally had letters on the x-axis and numbers on the y-axis

Comment: Yes, I edited post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about chess but this might be close:

```
library('tidyverse')

chessboard = function(n){
  if(n > 26){
    stop('Ya board too big!')
  }
  board = expand_grid(X = 1:n, Y = 1:n)
  board = board %>% 
    mutate(color = ifelse((X - Y) %% 2 == 0, 'black', 'white')) %>% 
    mutate_all(factor)
  letter_labs = LETTERS[1:n]


  ggplot(data = board, aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = color)) +
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('black' = "#FFFFFF", 'white' = "#000000")) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = letter_labs, name = '') +
    scale_y_discrete(labels = letter_labs, name = '') +
    theme(legend.position = 'none')

}
chessboard(10)
```